# find alphabet position in string and count string length

Tags: php

I'm trying to get position of alphabet in given string and also caculate full length of string and get position of alphabet in integer ( like index)

for example, Talha = 5 length, find T = 1

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['sub'])) 
    {
        $n = $_POST['name'];
        $f = $_POST['f']; 
        $s = strlen($n);  
        $res = strpos($f,$n);
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
 ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="f" placeholder="find" />
        <input type="submit" name="sub" />

 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
        echo "total words are". $s. "Your word is". $res; 
    }
 ?>
    </form>
```

Comment: I'm really sorry but I didn't understood the question, can you rephrase?

Comment: let suppose you said me my name is "Saikios" find a in it.. and tell me the location in wich place it belongs.. i will tell you its in 2nd place in your name.. :))

Comment: give us an example string and the desired result. But i think you want to `explode` `array_search` and/or `strpos`

Comment: basically this code finds a alphabet from string and shows its place... hope you understand now.. awaiting for correct ans..

Comment: @lolka_bolka example is this you input my name in text field.. "THINKER" now you input "E" in find text field now result will be something like this.. THINKER all char are 7 and E is belong to 6 position

Comment: Sidenote: You will need to modify your conditional statement a bit. If someone does not enter anything in the field(s) and clicks submit, they will get `Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in...`

Comment: @Mültï Thìnkër you should use javascript if you want to show to a user, or you can use php if it's for something else ;)

Comment: http://sscce.org/ Inputs, outputs (actual and expected), current attempt. That's all we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the arguments of strpos the wrong way around;

should be:

```
$res=strpos($n,$f)
```

Also if you want the answer to be human usable you may want to increment the $res by one:

```
$res=strpos($n,$f)+1
```

As strpos considers the first character as position zero (0)

Answer (score 0):

The only error I'm seeing is that you got your arguments backwards. You are doing strpos(needle, haystack). The arguments are like this:

```
strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

Haystack is where you want to look, needle is what you want to look up. So you'll have to do:

```
strpos($n, $f);
```

You want to search in $n, $f.

[PHP - Strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Edit: Also, strlen doesn't get you the total amount of words, but characters. You'll have to use this: [PHP - str_word_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

Answer (score 0):

The answers on here are right,
for what you are asking on php you should use strpos

however, if you want to show that to a user you should probably go with javascript or jquery
here you have a code on javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Search for Name</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var name = "saikios.";
    var n = name.indexOf("k");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    Char to search: <input type="text" name="char" /><br />
    Srting: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    if (strpos($_POST["name"], $_POST["char"]) !== false) {
        $words = explode(" ", trim($_POST["name"]));
        $wordsCnt = count($words);
        echo "total words are " . $wordsCnt."<br/>";
        echo "Name is: " . $_POST["name"]."<br/>";
        echo "Char what you search is " . $_POST["char"]."<br/>";
        echo "I found the first occurance your char at " . strpos($_POST["name"], $_POST["char"]);
    } else {
        echo "I do not found the character in the name!";
    }
}
```

So if i write `a` to char and `Haystack` to name you will get:

```
total words are 1
Name is: Haystack
Char what you search is a
I found the first occurance your char at 1
```